# Subsetting data frame suffix in R

Tags: r, subset

I'm new to R and I'm having a hard time removing those with -NWT suffix in a subsetting function below:

I've tried three lines I've seen on the internet but is still no luck:

```
trades.am <- subset(trades.am, Series.Name != "-NWT")
trades.am[trades.am$C != "-NWT", ]
sub.trades.am<-trades.am[trades.am[,3] != "-NWT",]
```

hope you guys can help.

Regards,

Comment: Please post a sample of your data (`dput(head(trades.am))`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
trades.am[!grepl("-NWT$", trades.am$Series.Name),]
#    Series.Name     value
#5    Something 1.6133728
#6    Something 0.0356312
#9    Something 0.8817912
#11   Something 0.9657529
#15   Something 1.9355718
```

#### Update

```
  vec1 <- c("FXTN 10-41*", "FXTN 90-21", "FXTN*")
  grepl("\\*$", vec1)
  # [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE

  vec1[!grepl("\\*$", vec1)]
  #[1] "FXTN 90-21"
```

#### data

```
set.seed(42)
trades.am <- data.frame(Series.Name= sample(c("Something-NWT", "Something",
                      "Some-NWT"),15, replace=TRUE), value=rnorm(15))
```

Comment: Thanks! :) is it also possible if I use it on data with asterisk (e.g FXTN 10-41*)   trades.am[!grepl("*$", trades.am$Series.Name),] ?

Comment: @Che-Che I updated the post.  You can do `trades.am[!grepl("\\*$", trades.am$Series.Name),]`